# How to compare two different sizes List Objects Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, compare

I have two Lists, List A and List B having different sizes. List A is getting parsed from file and List B is fetching data from the database.

```
class A{
    private String id;
    private String mobile;
}

class B{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String mobile;
    private String pincode;
}
```

Now I want to **Compare** both the list and want to remove the respective ids from **List A** which are having the same mobile number as **ListB**.

**Tried below code**

```
private List<A> compareList(List<A> listA, List<B> listB){
    List<A> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for(A a : listA){
        for(B b : listB){
            if(a.getId().equals(b.getId()) && !a.getMobile().equals(b.getMobile())){
                temp.add(a);
            }
        }
    }
return temp;
}
```

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Did you try anything? A way will be to make a set of ids from List of B. Then filter the List A by which id is not contained in set of ids of List B.

Comment: I tried this code but it's not working as expecting. `private List<A> compareList(List<A> listA, List<B> listB){
 List<A> temp = new ArrayList<>();
 for(A a : listA){
  for(B b : listB){
   if(a.getId().equals(b.getId()) && !a.getMobile().equals(b.getMobile())){
    temp.add(a);
   }
  }
 }
}`

Comment: you are adding the element to the temp list in the wrong place. You should add it to the list only after checking a is not any of the b elements instead of adding a if it is not each b element.

Answer (score 3):

Your method creates a new list, instead of removing items from the existing list. Assuming you actually want to remove items, this is one way you can do it with the Java 8 streams API: remove an item from listA if it has the same `mobile` as an item in listB:

```
listA.removeIf(a -> listB.stream()
                         .anyMatch(b -> Objects.equals(a.getMobile(), b.getMobile())));
```

The streams API in this case is a little difficult to read. Here's the same without using a stream:

```
for (B b : listB) {
    listA.removeIf(a -> Objects.equals(a.mobile, b.mobile));
}
```

Comment: removeIf is not working. it's returning the same size as if was earlier of List A

Comment: If it's not removing anything, it's because the predicate you pass in does not match any items. Are you sure you're comparing the mobile in A with the mobile in B and that listB contains an object that has the same mobile as an object in listA?

Comment: Comparison is not only for mobile number, but it also depends on id. The predicate is having the same id in both lists but mobile no is different.

Comment: Hmm in the question you say something different: "remove the respective ids from List A which are having the same mobile number as ListB" Perhaps it would clarify if you edited the question to include an example of the input and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag for existence and add in temp if not exists then temp contains only those elements of A which do not exist in B

```
List<A> temp = new ArrayList<>();
for(A a : listA){
    boolean isExist = false;
    for(B b : listB){
        if(a.getId().equals(b.getId()) && a.getMobile().equals(b.getMobile())){
            isExist = true; // if exist in List of B
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!isExist){   // if not exist in B then add in list
        temp.add(a);
    }
}
```

*Note:* In question you say to compare only mobile number but in code you are comparing id also, remove id equal check if you don't want it

Comment: ID is the same in file and database. I want to check which ids are having different mobile no in file and database, that's why there is check for ID.

Comment: @AkashPanwar Then this solution should work and update the question as per requirement

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep the mobiles separately, as they can probably be repeated. And after that compare the main collection with this list of mobiles.

```
private static List<A> compareList(List<A> listA, List<B> listB) {
    List<String> mobiles = listB.stream()
            .map(B::getMobile)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return listA.stream()
            .filter(entity -> !mobiles.contains(entity.getMobile()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To create new filtered List**

Collect all element in new list if condition does not match

```
List<A> filteredList =
        aList.stream()
            .filter(Predicate.not(a -> bList.stream().anyMatch(b -> a.getId().equals(b.getId()) && a.getMobile().equals(b.getMobile()))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**For in place replacement**

```
aList.removeIf(a -> bList.stream().anyMatch(b -> a.getId().equals(b.getId()) && a.getMobile().equals(b.getMobile())));
```